# Overloading Delphi methods with ambiguous parameter types leads to unexpected execution

Tags: delphi

I have two Equal method that take these overloads:

```
TVariantExpression = reference to function(): Variant;

function Equal(const value: Variant): TRuleBuilder; overload;
function Equal(expr: TVariantExpression): TRuleBuilder; overload;
```

suppose I have another function :

```
function TForm1.GetMagicNumber: Variant;
begin
  Result := 10;
end;
```

and I invoke function like this:

```
Equal(Form1.GetMagicNumber);
```

After inspecting, I get result that second overload is called. Why? because both of them is valid to be called.

Comment: not exactly. Address to function would be `@Form.GetMagicNumber` - and that address should yet be typecasted from `function of object` to `reference to function`. So i think you'd either make intermediate `reference to function` variable or try explicit `TVariantExpression(@Form.GetMagicNumber)`. Pascal is not C++ where any function name is a pointer by definition.

Comment: I don't know why, but, after inspecting using logger to determine which overload that called, I get that the second overlaod get called.

Comment: @arioch Using @ on procedural values is almost always a very bad idea. It takes you outside the type system. And forces you to cast.

Comment: Well, i always work in $T+ mode ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't see how $T+ helps here. I also always work in $T+ mode.

Comment: Then how does it "take out of type system" ?

Comment: If you use @functionname the compiler skips the parameter and return type checks, even if you have $T+. I myself ran into this issue. Code that worked for years crashed because somebody added an additional parameter but with the @-modifier the compiler didn't complain about the parameter mismatch.

Comment: @Arioch'The Have you ever tried assigning `@Button1Click` to a variable of type `TNotifyEvent`? See how much `$T+` helps you.

Comment: Wow, such a gotcha! thank you both, would have to know this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Form1.GetMagicNumber
```

is ambiguous. It can be either the function, or the value returned after executing the function. In most contexts, only one of those meanings is valid, and that meaning is chosen.

In your code, either meaning is valid. In such a scenario the language rules mean that the procedural type interpretation is chosen.

To force function invocation write:

```
Form1.GetMagicNumber()
```

This is a significant difference from most other languages, e.g. C, C++, C#, Java, Python etc. In those languages you must use parentheses in order to invoke a function.

Comment: Suppose, first, I have only first overload. And consumer of function call `Equal(Form1.GetMagicNumber);`. It will be perfectly valid. Later, I add second overload. That will silently change implementation which called. Right?

Comment: Haha.. I think it will lead to bugs that quite difficult to trace..
And without know signature of `Equal`, we don't even know what `Equal(Form1.GetMagicNumber);` do.

Answer (score 1):

it is because the first Equal Function have the same type parameter of the second Equal function !

When you do `$ ( TVariantExpression = reference to function(): Variant; )` the `TVariantExpression` take the Variant type as value.